# Using flutter_inAppWebView, how do I programmatically close the web view?

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I'm using [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) and I've got it working, but I want to programmatically close the web view and trigger `onCloseWindow` to emit an event.

I'm tried importing things like `dart:html as html` to try to use `html.window.close` but my linter doesn't seem to like that. I get `Error: Not found: 'dart:html` and `Error: undefined name` window`on top of a warning:`Avoid using web-only libraries outside Flutter web plugin packages.`.

How do I close this window to trigger `onCloseWindow`?

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is this:

`controller.evaluateJavascript(source: 'window.close();');`

However, triggering `onCloseWindow` does not close the webview, but rather using `Nagivator.pop(context)` as I have a Scaffold page and putting the `InAppWebView` in the body.